# How to import a root directory

Tags: python, import

I don't understand one thing about import in python.
I have a /scripts/my_python directory with my libs.
This code works good :

```
sys.path.append('/scripts')
from my_python.my_lib import *
# my_function is declared in my_lib
my_function()
```

But this code doesn't work (my_function is not defined)

```
sys.path.append('/scripts/my_python')
from my_lib import *
# my_function is declared in my_lib
my_function()
```

And I don't understand what is the difference.
I have read this doc http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages but all examples are a subdirectory.

Comment: Can you mention the error you were getting

Comment: my_lib may be in another directory
try 
import my_lib //in the second import eg
print dir(mylib)
to see the functions in my_lib

Comment: print dir(my_lib) => my_lib is not defined

Comment: have you imported mylib as import my_lib